# Transforming xml to xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very much beginner in XSLT. I am trying to transform this XML :

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <A id="1">
                <I/><T/>
            </A>
            <A id="2">
                <I/><T/>
            </A>
        </C>
        <C>
            <A id="3">
                <I/><T/>
            </A>
            <A id="4">
                <I/> <T/>
            </A>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

to something like :

```
<A>
    <B>  
        <A id="1">
            <I/> <T/> 
        </A>
        <A id="2"/> 
            <I/> </T> 
        </A>
        <A id="3">
            <I/> <T/> 
        </A>
        <A id="4"/> 
            <I/> <T/> 
        </A>
    </B> 
</A>
```

As you can see here I have 2 'C' tag blocks under 'B' tag block. I want get rid of the 'C' tag and add all sub 'A' tags under 'B' tag and also I need 'I' and 'T' tags within 'A'..

Could someone please help me on this one?

Comment: This should be really easy. Please try it first by yourself.

Comment: SHould I separately declare 4 'A' tags like this <xsl:template match="A[0]"> ??? for A[1],A[2] etc ???

Comment: Have a look for xslt i dentity transform (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) and add a match for B without xsl:copy (only applay-templates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as Ian says:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="C">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: torazaburo Thank you..I have a question though.. I have a tag say <A1 identity=1 > ,how can I transform it into <A2 id=1> ? I want to change the name of the attribute within the tag and also the tag name.

Comment: Just add new templates for each case. For instance, `<xsl:template match="A1"> <A2 id="{@identity}"> <xsl:apply-templates/> </A2> </xsl:template>`.

Comment: Hi,..Just a another question..Now I have 4 "A" tags..How can I access 3rd and 4th "A" tag..IN case I need to set different attribute values for each tag..

Comment: `<xsl:template match="A[position()=3]"`